# JAVA Regex Explain

Tags: regex

[01]?\d{1,2}
can someone please explain the complete meaning of the above line.

Comment: You can try out any online regex explaining site like [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern describes a text that might (but not must) start with a 0 or 1 (`[01]?`) followed by one to two digits (`\d{1,2}`).

Answer (score 0):

In short, this pattern used to test a number between 000 and 199. [01]? means a number starts with 0 or 1, and \d{1,2} means a one-digit or two-digit number.